# IDE for Go (golang) with deployment/upload

Tags: deployment, ide, go

is there an IDE for the Go language that can easily deploy/upload files to the server?

ideally I am looking for an IDE that can automatically upload the files to the server each time I decide to run the app, like I can do with PyCharm for python

Comment: vim + appcfg.py > everything else.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya I have just read that appcfg.py is distributed with Google App Engine tools. Can I still use it if I am deploying to my own server?

Comment: No, you must use GAE.

Comment: by the way, does it make sense to use GO with your own server, or you are recommended to use GAE?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/), now it has working [Go plugin](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin), to build the latest plugin, visit this [tutorial](http://kokizzu.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-to-build-latest-go-idea-plugin.html).

Comment: Are you sure that GIT repository exists? It gives me an error

Comment: if you have not configure github ssh keys, use https cloning `git clone https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin.git`

Comment: Hi @Kokizzu, yes the problem was related to the key. I managed to clone the repository with this latest command.

Comment: However I am not able to follow the tutorial:
1) "Build > Build Artifacts..." is not enabled
2) I don't know where to find Go.zip

Comment: See at the bottom of the post, I've already upload the `Go.zip` for those who has difficulties (since yesterday)..

Comment: Right now it has a stable version in the repository, just open your IDE **Preferences | Plugins** and search **Go**.

Answer (score 0):

I use LiteIDE for editing, and command line appcfg.py for uploading. If you are not familiar with command line, here is a quick sample:

```
appcfg.py update your_app_folder --oauth2
```

Just save this string somewhere and copy and paste to CMD when you need it.

Comment: I have just read that appcfg.py is distributed with Google App Engine tools. Can I still use it if I am deploying to my own server?

Comment: @DanieleB oops I assumed you are using GAE but in case you are not... I'm not quite sure how you can deploy it to your own server.

Are you using AppScale? http://www.appscale.com/

Comment: Actually I am not. I was not even aware of it. I would like to use Go to use some REST webservices and I am wondering how easy is to deploy/update code to the server